# Actualizar varias filas desde foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo este DataGridView con esta columna  Vendedor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo en SQL server la tabla donde se guarda esta información cada vez que en el DataGridView Cambie la columna vendedor debe cambiar en SQL server

**codigo que hace el cambio**

```
   using (var connection = conexion.AbrirConexion())
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "SP_UpdateProvedorT";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView6.Rows)
                        {
                            #region CAMPOS ACTUALIZAR
                            command.Parameters.Clear();
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value));
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Provedor", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[27].Value));
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Procedimiento de SQL SERVER

```
CREATE PROC  [dbo].[SP_UpdateProvedorT]
@Provedor NVARCHAR(50), 
@Number INT
AS
UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenT]  SET vendedor =@Provedor WHERE workOrderNumber =@Number
```

Pero al ejecutar me repite las filas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás actualizando tres veces las tres filas. El problema es que no tienes algo que identifique de forma única las filas para poder actualizar cada una con el valor correspondiente.

Si en tu tabla hay una forma de identificar las filas dentro de la misma orden de trabajo, debes usar todos los campos que generan ese identificador único. Quedaría algo así.

```
CREATE PROC  [dbo].[SP_UpdateProvedorT]
    @Provedor NVARCHAR(50), 
    @Number INT,
    @RowNum INT
AS
UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_DetalleOrdenT]  SET 
       vendedor = @Provedor 
WHERE workOrderNumber = @Number 
AND   NumeroLinea = @RowNum; -- esta condición depende de la estructura de tu tabla
```